# how to enforce function type in typescript

Tags: typescript

TypeScript Version 3.5.1

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEoHMDOyDeAUMsjAPZkBcyIArgLYBG0A3IQL6GFgCeADigCyPAGK0QCZAF5kACjjYc1DIoCU0gHzIAClDL1gOCAB44IHhraEA9NeQB3ABY9kAEzIQc4ZGEeHkCPp8ADZwoAD8Nna+0Cj+IGSkwFA4YMgKWAwQ3jgCCMAwwBCuAHSEgSCppCDUwmIS0uk4PBKy6lJaRBxW1gBUxMjigfT02WCgWD6OKOTBwWT2E8jBoCiLc8j0cADWKDE+eMN8wMHQyANHoaDLwLvIwGk4jmS0wa4ANMiMtGkPyE8vN4AcgAbihLmEQMV7iABvs4IwyGC3BAEKEoHBxmQQE0HBA5pFetYuLZqm0WEA)

I have a simple type for a function that requires arguments be sent in. However, when I declare a function of that type, there is no complaint from the TypeScript compiler when no arguments are specified. Here is a simple example.

```
interface IArgs {
  foo: number;
}

type MyFunc = (args: IArgs) => Promise<any>;

// why doesnt this complain?
// there is no first argument specified.
const fn: MyFunc = async() => { };

/*
  uncommenting the following line will make the ts compiler 
  complain like it should, but it should've complained in
  the above declaration as well?
*/

// fn();
```

How can i get the TypeScript compiler to complain about missing arguments in function declarations?

Comment: That's [intended behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters); Is there some reason why you need it to fail to compile?  It behaves almost exactly the same as `async(args: IArgs) => {}`, a function which ignores its argument.

Comment: Yes it does appear to be a duplicate. As far as why, it was just a strange behavior I had a question about. Thank you for the link to the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!

I think this is a deliberate design choice typescript is making here.

It is valid to choose not to use arguments in a function, but it is not valid to omit arguments when *calling* a function.

Take a click handler, for example:

```
type ClickHandler = (evt: MouseEvent) => any

// Valid uses:
element.onClick = () => doSomething()
element.onClick = (evt) => doSomething(evt.target.value)
```

However, because some ClickHandler functions may use the argument, and some may not, it *must* always be provided.

```
const fn: ClickHandler = () => {}
fn() // typescript error
```

Comment: OK. This makes sense. Thank you!